# Is there a best approach for statistical power for field experiment?

Tags: experiment-design, ecology, pooling, pseudorepliction

I'm setting up a field experiment and want to make a solid plan for the analysis, since that's whereI get stressed in the process.  I will deploy 26 pairs of traps. 13 pairs will be in urban forest, and the other half will be in rural forests.  The 13 urban forest sites will be distinct from each other (13 local parks), while the rural forest traps will be placed within a forest (approx 35,000 acres).  I'd use the urban sites as separate replicates and was hoping to do the same thing for the rural traps. If significantly spaced out in the national forest using watershed or another characteristic, would I still need to pool all traps from the 35,000 acre forest for analysis, because of the technicality that they're within the same site?  Is there a better approach?  The main question involved the paired traps, but the urban/rural component is an additional factor.

Comment: It would depend on what you are trapping.  What is the expected/typical range of the animal you are trapping?  If it is squirrel, I wouldn't expect that they travel more than a few hundred feet so if the traps are set farther apart they could be consider independent.